# retriving data from SD card in multiple text boxes

Tags: android

code for saving in SD card,i have declared button save where registered onclicklistner as follows:

```
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {       
    EditText filename =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filename);
            EditText filecontent =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filecontent);
       public void onClick(View view) 
        {

        String str = filename.getText().toString();
        String str2= filecontent.getText().toString();

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFiles");
            directory.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(directory,"textfile.txt");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                osw.write(str);
            osw.write("   ");
            osw.write(str2);
                    osw.close();


        }

       }
```

on load button i have registered onclicklistener while defined block as well
        private static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;
while load code is:

```
    Button load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load);
    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
EditText filename =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filename);
    EditText filecontent =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filecontent);
    public void onClick(View v) {

       File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() +
        "/MyFiles");
        File file = new File(directory, "textfile.txt");

        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
             char[] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s = "";
        int charRead;

    while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
    {
        //---convert the chars to a String---
        String readString =
        String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
        charRead);
        s += readString;
        inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
    }

  filename.setText(s);
  filecontent.setText(s);
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
  "File loaded successfully!",
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  });
```

its showing all contents of files in each textbox!!i want filename  to b extracted from content !!

Comment: Why are you saving the filename as part of the file content? When you come to read it back you already know the filename (otherwise you wouldn't be able to open/read it) so why put it in there in the first place?

Comment: @MisterSquonk It seems from OP's code that the file name being saved is not the same as the name of the file in which it's being saved.

Comment: @Ted: Ah, good point - I was going cross-eyed trying to work out what the code was meant to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the file to be human readable, I'd suggest storing the two String values as serialized Java objects using DataInputStream/DataOutputStream:

**Writing:**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String str = filename.getText().toString();
    String str2= filecontent.getText().toString();

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File (sdCard, "MyFiles");
    directory.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(directory, "textfile.txt");
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(fOut);
    os.writeUTF(str);
    os.writeUTF(str2);
    os.close();
}
```

**Reading:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {    
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File (sdCard, "MyFiles");
    File file = new File(directory, "textfile.txt");

    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(fIn);
    String name = is.readUTF();
    String content = is.readUTF();
    is.close();

    filename.setText(name);
    filecontent.setText(content);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
        "File loaded successfully!",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Note, however, that it is recommended that all I/O to the SDCard be done in a worker thread. It's not good practice to do it in an event handler like this. Much better to fire up an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for each.

Comment: See the [blog entry on StrictMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) for a nice explanation of why all I/O should be done off the UI thread. Also, you should protect your code against IOException problems. At a minimum, the calls to `close()` should be in `finally` blocks.